# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I've looked around through the jQuery docs and google and I can't seem to figure this out, though I have a feeling it's probably something really obvious I'm missing. For some reason, I get this error,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

,everytime I try and execute my script and I have no idea why (I've tried the script with and without the two `-` negative signs but it doesn't make a difference).

Here's my code:

```
$('.head').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({text-indent:'-60px'},100);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({text-indent:'-50px'},200);
});
```

Comment: You probably need to either quote text-indent ('text-indent') or use camel case (textIndent).

Comment: @jo8691 thanks, can't believe I overlooked that. Anyways, next time post the answer as an actual answer (instead of a comment) so I can mark it down as an answer (and give you credit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.head').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({'text-indent':'-60px'},100);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({'text-indent':'-50px'},200);
});
```